# How do I change terminal font size in kali 2020.2

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, fontconfig

I've just installed the kali 2020.2 with kali-linux-2020.2-installer-amd64.iso in VMware 15.1.0. And I choose the default desktop environment "xfce".

Everything looks good except when I open the terminal, the font size is too small that I almost can't see it.

I clicked the "file" => "propertities" => "font" in terminal and changed the font size from 10 to 20.

But after I clicked the "ok" button, nothing happened. And from the "properties" view, the font size is still 10.

Could anyone tell me how to change the font size in the terminal in kali 2020.2? Thank you.

Comment: Try to use a fixed / monospaced font. I had seen the same issue on xfce4-terminal on Debian if I recall well.

Comment: @Krackout Thank you for your reply. What does " a fixed / monospaced font" mean? Does it mean I should install another monospace font that has been fixed?
I've tried monospace font in the terminal, but the font was not changed. How strange it is! Neither the operation of font size nor font works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you can zoom in terminal with control + “+”  [^+]and zoom out with control + “-“ [^-]

But if you want to edit INTERNAL TERMINAL SIZE ...then :

Open terminal
Click EDIT>PREFERENCES>PROFILES

Now you can create a profile or edit current one you have and costumize as you want

Comment: Thank you @aris. Yeah, I know the hotkey `ctrl + '+'`. But I think it is really a trouble to click this hotkey every time I use the terminal.   What's worse is that, it seems that there is no such "PREFERENCES" in "EDIT" in my kali-linux-2020.2

Comment: Preferences may also be in the FILE on terminal if you search you will find it

Comment: Thank you @aris, but I still can't find it. Maybe one of the reasons for the small font and small icon is that my computer's resolution is 2560×1600. So sad :(

Comment: It should be there ...    can you send some screenshots to see what’s wrong because this is really strange I can’t vote this post cause I’m a new member with low reputation but I will do so if i get 15 reputation I hope you will find the fix 

Comment: Aha, that's ok. But I'm using the Chinese language on my interface. Is that ok to share you with the screenshot?  : )

Comment: I’m Greek actually so no way .                                    but maybe that’s the reason why you can’t find it I suggest you search everything in FILE and EDIT and you will find this

Comment: Well, Ummm, I think maybe there's a trick. I mean we can see where the "PREFERENCES" is in your terminal. And I check in mine to see if the corresponding position exists the "PREFERENCES". However it is going, thank you all the same aris : )

Answer (score 3):

You can change config file located in

```
/home/<username>/.config/qterminal.org/qterminal.ini
```

default font size is 10, find the *fontSize* option and change it to the size you want!

Comment: Just notice that when you close the terminal it saves its config back to the ini file, so close any terminals in advance and edit the ini file with another program

Answer (score 1):

Changing the font size in their default terminal just doesn't seem to work, no matter what I've tried. Here's my workaround:

```
sudo apt install xfce4-terminal
```

Once it's installed, go to "Settings" -> "Keyboard" -> "Application Shortcuts", and change it so that in future when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> it defaults to the new, easier to read, terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Using terminal in Ubuntu 20.04, open terminal selected preferences from the hamburger menu,and under the default profile checked custom font and selected the size next to the font. Not sure about other distributions.

Answer (score 0):

- Click on *File* -> *Prefences* -> *Font* -> *Edit settings*. After that you can change your font size.
- To zoom in and zoom out: click on *Edit* -> *Zoom in* or *Zoom out*.